# Scaladoc wrap at right margin in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scaladoc

Is there any way you can make IntelliJ wrap scaladoc at the margin?

Basically, I want this:

```
/**
 * This is a method description that is long enough to exceed right margin.
 * <p/>
 * Another paragraph of the description placed after blank line.
 * <p/>
 * Line with manual
 * line feed.
```

to be formatted to this:

```
/**
 * This is a method description that is long
 * enough to exceed right margin.
 * <p/>
 * Another paragraph of the description
 * placed after blank line.
 * <p/>
 * Line with manual line feed.
 *
```

... if the line length is set to end here:

```
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dedicated setting for that - ['Ensure right margin is not exceeded'](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/wrapping-and-braces.html)